# mysql query tuning on multi-language table

Tags: mysql

I have a large table (multi-language table) that I need to optimize the queries I use for search

The structure of the table is :

```
table products
    productID
    code
    price

table products_lang
    productID
    lang
    product_name
    sub_title
    status
```

The tables right now have 240.000 records each

When I want to search for product_name I use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.productID)

FROM products as p

INNER JOIN products_lang as l ON
l.productID=p.productID
AND lang='en'                   

WHERE     
(l.productName LIKE '%keyword%') 

AND l.status =  '1' 

ORDER BY  p.price desc  
LIMIT 0,10
```

From the query I get only the ids that match query and then I query the products_lang only for these ids to get anything else

The thing is that the query above needs 2-3 secs which is too much

If I do the search directly to products_lang

```
SELECT DISTINCT(l.productID)

FROM products_lang as l

WHERE 

l.lang='en'                 

AND (l.productName LIKE '%keyword%') 
AND l.status =  '1' 

LIMIT 0,10
```

is much faster but I don’t have the ORDER BY p.price desc (because I have remove the JOIN)

Can anyone help me do the queries faster or break the query in 2 smaller to minimize the query time

Thanks

Comment: Do you have index  on product_lang status ?.. show your schema please

Answer (score 0):

Add proper index on the filter row for the table   products_lang and (just a minor) remove the unuseful ()  around some filter condition

```
INDEX your_name  (status ,productName ,productID )
```

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.productID)

FROM products as p

INNER JOIN products_lang as l ON l.productID=p.productID AND l.lang='en'                   

WHERE    l.productName LIKE '%keyword%'
AND l.status =  '1' 

ORDER BY  p.price desc  
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to USE `EXISTS` instead of joining two Tables

```
SELECT p.productID
FROM products as p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products_lang as l WHERE l.productID=p.productID AND 
                                                 lang='en' AND
                                                 l.status =  '1' AND 
                                                 l.productName LIKE '%keyword%')
ORDER BY  p.price desc  
LIMIT 0,10
```